# Count distinct in infinite stream

Tags: apache-spark, count, stream, apache-kafka, apache-flink

I am looking for a way to create a streaming application that can withstand millions of events per second and output a distinct count of those events in real time. As this stream is unbounded by any time window it obviously has to be backed by some storage. However, I cannot find the best way to do this maintaining a good level of abstraction (meaning that I want a framework to handle storing and counting for me, otherwise I don't need a framework at all). The preferred storage for me are Cassandra and Redis (both ideally).

The options I've considered are Flink, Spark and Kafka Streams. I do know the differences between them, but I still can't pick the best solution. Can someone advice? Thanks in advance.

Comment: spark structured streaming has some examples around similar use case, please check that https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html

Comment: Can you elaborate by what you mean by "output a distinct count of those events in real time"? E.g. do you want to emit a record (say in Flink) every time the unique count changes? Or is it on some regular time boundary?

Comment: And can you partition the data, or is this a global unique count?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regardless of which solution you choose, if you can withstand it not being 100% accurate (but being very very close), you can have your operator using [HyperLogLog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HyperLogLog) (there are Java implementations available). This allows you to not actually have to keep around data about each individual item, drastically reducing your memory usage.

Assuming Flink, the necessary state is quite small (< 1MB), so can easily use the `FSStateBackend` which is heap-based and checkpoints to the file system, allowing you to reduce serialization overhead.

Again assuming you go with Flink, Using the `[ContinuousEventTimeTrigger][2]`, you can also get a view into how many unique items are currently being tracked.

Comment: I know about HLL and it is probably the way I will go for. I just wanted to know if it's possible to achieve something like this with Flink-like solutions. I will consider using it with the HLL-operator. Thanks.

Comment: Ah cool, yes I have successfully done this using the clearspring implementation. Depending on your needs, you may need to override serialization, however I think the default one that Kryo will generate should work fine for checkpointing. If you use RocksDB it could end up being a bit slow due to the constant serialization/deserialization

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest to reconsider the choice of storage system. Using an external system is significantly slower than using local state. Flink applications locally maintain state on the JVM heap or in RocksDB (on disk) and can checkpoint it in regular intervals to persistent storage such as HDFS. This state can grow very big (10s of TBs) and still be efficiently maintained because checkpoints can be incrementally and asynchronously done. This gives much better performance than sending a query to an external system for each record.

If you still prefer Redis or Cassandra, you can use Flink's AsyncIO operator to send asynchronous requests to improve the throughput of your application.